# How to host sonatype nexus oss on azure web app

Tags: azure, cloud, nexus, sonatype

I have tried installing nexus on azure VM but how can we host nexus oss as website on azure web apps?

For web-app purpose i tried two ways
1> deploy it from github nexus oss link,(as external source control) not sure what else it needs to be up.
2> I tried putting available nexus oss WAR in both tomcat as well as jetty configured web-app

Comment: You may have to post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Azure VM runs a supported operating system (Windows, Linux) and has a supported Java installed (Java 7 or Java 8 from Oracle), you can install it from the bundle like on any other operating system.

Further [instructions for installation and much more are in the Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install.html). If you run into specific problems you can also [contact us via various means.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/lists-live-chat-and-other-resources/)

Note that running Nexus in a different container from the Eclipse Jetty servlet container that is part of the bundle installer is NOT supported.